# How to restrict selection with QueryOver in (fluent) nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, queryover

I want to filter objects from the db by a property that comes from another object but i get an exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.QueryException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'NHibernate.QueryException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
>   The program '[5116] Examples.FirstProject.vshost.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code -532459699 (0xe0434f4d).

This works:

```
var curves = session.QueryOver<Curve>().WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.Name).IsLike("%CurveName%").List();
foreach (Curve curve in curves)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" ID:\t{0}\n Name:\t{1}\n Group:\t{2}\n", curve.Id, curve.Name, curve.Group.Name);
}
```

This not, it outputs the exception information:

```
var curves = session.QueryOver<Curve>().WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.Group.Name).IsLike("%GroupName%").List();
foreach (Curve curve in curves)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" ID:\t{0}\n Name:\t{1}\n Group:\t{2}\n", curve.Id, curve.Name, curve.Group.Name);
}
```

These are my mappings:

```
public class CurveMap : ClassMap<Curve>
{
    public CurveMap()
    {
        Table("CURVES");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("CURVE_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("NAME");
        References(x => x.Group).Column("GROUP_ID");
    }
}

public class CurveGroupMap : ClassMap<CurveGroup>
{
    public CurveGroupMap()
    {
        Table("GROUPS");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("GROUP_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("NAME");
        HasMany(x => x.Curves).KeyColumn("GROUP_ID").Cascade.All().Inverse();
    }
}
```

And these are my objects

```
public class Curve
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CurveGroup Group { get; set; }
}

public class CurveGroup
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Curve> Curves { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea, how to fix this. I am new to (fluent) nhibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you join CurveGroup and use Aliases it will work:

```
CurveGroup cgAlias = null;
var curves = session.QueryOver<Curve>()
    .JoinAlias(e => e.Group, () => cgAlias)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => cgAlias.Name).IsLike("%GroupName%").List();
```

Comment: Works, but seems to be convoluted. Is there a simpler way to achieve this or why doe it have to be this way. Could you elaborate your answer and give more details.

Comment: @mrt181 It seems that by design, QueryOver does not navigate association paths on its own. You have to explicitly specify that in the Query. If the association paths are not specified an exception "could not resolve property" is thrown. (See [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx#Associations) for more details on `JoinAlias` and `JoinQueryOver`.